# Rich text field adding &nbsp; and normal space char at random

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is there any rhyme or reason to the adding of non-breaking spaces or traditional space? It seems to appear at random throughout the content in my rich text fields.

Comment: Yep I'd like to know as well how to prevent Redactor adding those pesky `&nbsp;` all over the place. Seems the problem is worse with redactor 2.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that this happens when you end a line or string with a space and put nothing after it.

"Text "
 becomes "Text "

If you then copy "Text " and paste it repeatedly you'd end up with "Text Text Text Text Text Text "

Same for a lone space on a line.

" "
 becomes ";nbsp"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Redactor. There has been an [ongoing bug report about it here](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285224-bugs/suggestions/11027331-redactor-2-adds-extra-non-breaking-spaces).
But I found that if you use Firefox it doesn't add the non-breaking spaces when editing.

onebrightlight (on Slack) suggested a temporary fix to replace them with spaces in your template code:

```
{{ entry.fieldname | replace({'&nbsp;' : ''})|raw }}
```